# Is there a way to hook into JComponent.paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, gradient, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I need to use gradient color on some of the controls in my application. Following an example, I created my own JGradientPanel that extends JPanel and overrode its paintComponent method. Now, I could use JGradientPanel instead of JPanel and things work okay. I need to extend the logic to JButton, JLabel and many other components. Instead of creating my own custom components for each of them, I am wondering if there is a better way to somehow hook into any component that I need to use a gradient color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an own [LookAndFeel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html). You might look into the code of other L&Fs, as it is not fully documented.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was hoping there is a simpler way for what I was trying to do. Regards, Peter.

Comment: The functionality of a ComponentUI or say [ButtonUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ButtonUI.html) is not overly complex, but you are right, might take much experimenting.